# Omnetpp.ini - How to create loop for the host parametres

Tags: omnet++

I have 1000 hosts. I need to simulate the situation when host[0] connects with other 999 hosts by PingApp in accordance with a timetable.

For example

```
**.host[0]*.numPingApps = 999 #number of hosts

**.host[0]*.pingApp[*].typename = "PingApp"

**.host[0]*.pingApp[*].packetSize = 42 B

**.host[0]*.pingApp[*].sendInterval = 1 s

**.host[0]*.pingApp[*].srcAddr = "host[0]"

**.host[0]*.pingApp[0].destAddr = "host[1]" 

**.host[0]*.pingApp[0].startTime = 0 s

**.host[0]*.pingApp[0].stopTime = 5s

**.host[0]*.pingApp[1].destAddr = "host[2]" 

**.host[0]*.pingApp[1].startTime = 0.1 s

**.host[0]*.pingApp[1].stopTime = 5.1 s

**.host[0]*.pingApp[2].destAddr = "host[3]" 

**.host[0]*.pingApp[2].startTime = 0.2 s

**.host[0]*.pingApp[2].stopTime = 5.2 s

**.host[0]*.pingApp[3].destAddr = "host[4]" 

**.host[0]*.pingApp[3].startTime = 0.3 s

**.host[0]*.pingApp[3].stopTime = 5.3 s
```

and so on...

How can I create the loop for automatic changes of parameters: startTime, stopTime, destAddr, number of pingApp?
I need to increase startTime and stopTime by 0.1s at every step of one point increase of pingApp number and destAddr.

Help me please!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combined answers of @Rudi and @JerzyD. and got the workable solution:

```
**.host[0]*.numPingApps = 999
**.host[0]*.pingApp[*].typename = "PingApp"
**.host[0]*.pingApp[*].sendInterval = 1 s
**.host[0]*.pingApp[*].packetSize = 42 B
**.host[0]*.pingApp[0..998].destAddr = "host[" + string(index()+1) + "]"
**.host[0]*.pingApp[0..998].startTime = replaceUnit (0.1 * (index()), "s")
**.host[0]*.pingApp[0..998].stopTime = replaceUnit (5 + 0.1 * (index()), "s")
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer, I suggest to format it correctly as a code block and mark this one as the correct one, so other users will see this in the future, too. Self answers are allowed, but you will have to wait a few days before you can mark your own answer.

Comment: @Rudi Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, every host should have only one Ping Application. To achieve your goal you can use the following settings:

```
**.host[*].numApps = 1
**.host[*].app[0].typename = "PingApp"

**.host[999].app[0].destAddr = "host[0]"
**.host[*].app[0].destAddr = "host[" + string(parentIndex()+1) + "]"

**.host[*].app[0].startTime = replaceUnit (0.1*(parentIndex()), "s")
**.host[*].app[0].stopTime = replaceUnit (5 + 0.1*(parentIndex()), "s")
```

The `paretnIndex()` returns the index of the host in vector of hosts, reference [OMNeT++ Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-functions:category-ned). For the last node (i.e. `host[999]`) `destAddr` is set by hand because `parentIndex()+1` will return 1000, and there is no `host[1000]`.
The second NED function - `replaceUnit()` - is used to [add the unit](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-functions:category-units) to the result of calculation.

Comment: Note that this solution creates a kind of ring topology between the sending hosts while OP was asking about something where host[0] is the only sending node and it pings all the other hosts sequentially one by one. As changing the destination address during runtime is not supported by the ping application, without code changes to the PingApp's C++ code, I see no other way than indeed creating 999 ping apps with different parameters. Instead of using `parentIndex()`, you should use `index` and `host[0].numApps=999`  should be specified. This is a waste of resources tough...

Comment: @Rudi: yes, you are right. I didn't read the question carefully.

Comment: @Rudi: I combined your answers and I got a workable solution. Thank you!!! Check it if you want.

Comment: @JerzyD. I combined your answers and I got a workable solution. Thank you!!! Check it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other quasi solution:
From the PingApp's documentation:

> string destAddr = default(""); // destination address(es), separated by spaces, "*" means all IPv4/IPv6 interfaces in entire simulation
>
> Specifying '*' allows pinging ALL configured network interfaces in the
> whole simulation. This is useful to check if a host can reach ALL other
> hosts in the network (i.e. routing tables were set up properly).
>
> To specify the number of ping requests sent to a single destination address,
> use the 'count' parameter. After the specified number of ping requests was
> sent to a destination address, the application goes to sleep for 'sleepDuration'.
> Once the sleep timer has expired, the application switches to the next destination
> and starts pinging again. The application stops pinging once all destination
> addresses were tested or the simulation time reaches 'stopTime'.

So if you have only these hosts in the network and you don't mind that in the beginning the host pings itself too, `destAddr="*"`  and `count=1`